# argument getting truncated while printing in unix after merging files

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am trying to combine two tab seperated text files but one of the fields is being truncated by awk when I use the command (pls suggest something other than awk if it is easier to do so)

```
pr -m -t test_v1 test.predict | awk -v OFS='\t' '{print $4,$5,$7}' > out_test8
```

The format of the test_v1 is

```
478     192     46      10203853138191712
```

but I only print  10203853138 for $4 truncating the other digits. Should I use string format? 
Actually I found out after a suggestion given that pr -m -t itself does not give the correct output

```
478^I192^I46^I10203853138^I^I  is the output of the command
 pr -m -t test_v1 test.predict | cat -vte
```

I used paste test_v1 test.predict instead of pr and got the right answer.

Comment: Can you show output of `pr -m -t test_v1 test.predict | cat -vte` command

Comment: 478^I192^I46^I10203853138^I^I is the output of the command. So truncation happens even before.

Comment: As you can see your column is already truncated from `pr` command.

Comment: How can I avoid this truncation?

Comment: ok can you show output of `cat -vte test.predict` command?

Comment: Also `cat -vte test_v1`. My prediction is that `test_v1` has DOS line endings, and `test.predict` is mostly identical to `test_v1` and is overwriting the output of `test_v1`.

Comment: 478^I192^I46^I10203853138191712^I$ is the output for test_v1 and 0^I0^I0.25853681016272151^I$
for test.predict

Comment: Ok the paste command works fine and I solved it using paste instead of pr command for now.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is use `pr -m` (merge) here which as per manual:

> `-m, --merge`
>
> print all files in parallel, one in each column, **truncate lines**, but join lines of full length with -J

You can use:

```
paste test_v1 test.predict
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `dos2unix` on your files first, you've just got control-Ms in your input file(s).